# Вырезать emoji из строки

Tags: php, mysql, кодировка

Кодировка моей базы данных в utfmb4. Соответственно поддерживаются смайлы Emoji.
Но у меня нет желания, чтобы эти смайлы работали в базовой информации.

$profileinfo['fullname']

Эта переменная выводит Имя и фамилию пользователя. Как мне заставить её выводить только текст, не смотря на то, что кроме текста там находятся и Emoji ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно отфильтровать всё, кроме букв и цифр

```
$fullname = preg_replace ("/[^a-zA-ZА-Яа-я0-9\s]/","",$profileinfo['fullname'] );
```

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12807176/php-writing-a-simple-removeemoji-function
Здесь есть ответ, удалить можно так

```
function remove_emoji($text){
    return preg_replace('/[\x{1F3F4}](?:\x{E0067}\x{E0062}\x{E0077}\x{E006C}\x{E0073}\x{E007F})|[\x{1F3F4}](?:\x{E0067}\x{E0062}\x{E0073}\x{E0063}\x{E0074}\x{E007F})|[\x{1F3F4}](?:\x{E0067}\x{E0062}\x{E0065}\x{E006E}\x{E0067}\x{E007F})|[\x{1F3F4}](?:\x{200D}\x{2620}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F3F3}](?:\x{FE0F}\x{200D}\x{1F308})|[\x{0023}\x{002A}\x{0030}\x{0031}\x{0032}\x{0033}\x{0034}\x{0035}\x{0036}\x{0037}\x{0038}\x{0039}](?:\x{FE0F}\x{20E3})|[\x{1F441}](?:\x{FE0F}\x{200D}\x{1F5E8}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F467}\x{200D}\x{1F467})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F467}\x{200D}\x{1F466})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F467})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F466}\x{200D}\x{1F466})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F466})|[\x{1F468}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F468}\x{200D}\x{1F467}\x{200D}\x{1F467})|[\x{1F468}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F468}\x{200D}\x{1F466}\x{200D}\x{1F466})|[\x{1F468}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F468}\x{200D}\x{1F467}\x{200D}\x{1F466})|[\x{1F468}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F468}\x{200D}\x{1F467})|[\x{1F468}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F468}\x{200D}\x{1F466})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F469}\x{200D}\x{1F467}\x{200D}\x{1F467})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F469}\x{200D}\x{1F466}\x{200D}\x{1F466})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F469}\x{200D}\x{1F467}\x{200D}\x{1F466})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F469}\x{200D}\x{1F467})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F469}\x{200D}\x{1F466})|[\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{2764}\x{FE0F}\x{200D}\x{1F469})|[\x{1F469}\x{1F468}](?:\x{200D}\x{2764}\x{FE0F}\x{200D}\x{1F468})|[\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{2764}\x{FE0F}\x{200D}\x{1F48B}\x{200D}\x{1F469})|[\x{1F469}\x{1F468}](?:\x{200D}\x{2764}\x{FE0F}\x{200D}\x{1F48B}\x{200D}\x{1F468})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{1F9B3})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{1F9B3})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{1F9B3})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{1F9B3})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{1F9B3})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F9B3})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{1F9B2})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{1F9B2})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{1F9B2})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{1F9B2})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{1F9B2})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F9B2})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{1F9B1})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{1F9B1})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{1F9B1})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{1F9B1})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{1F9B1})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F9B1})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{1F9B0})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{1F9B0})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{1F9B0})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{1F9B0})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{1F9B0})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F9B0})|[\x{1F575}\x{1F3CC}\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}](?:\x{FE0F}\x{200D}\x{2640}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F575}\x{1F3CC}\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}](?:\x{FE0F}\x{200D}\x{2642}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F46E}\x{1F575}\x{1F482}\x{1F477}\x{1F473}\x{1F471}\x{1F9D9}\x{1F9DA}\x{1F9DB}\x{1F9DC}\x{1F9DD}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F645}\x{1F646}\x{1F481}\x{1F64B}\x{1F647}\x{1F926}\x{1F937}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F6B6}\x{1F3C3}\x{1F9D6}\x{1F9D7}\x{1F9D8}\x{1F3CC}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F3CA}\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}\x{1F6B4}\x{1F6B5}\x{1F938}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F939}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{2640}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F46E}\x{1F575}\x{1F482}\x{1F477}\x{1F473}\x{1F471}\x{1F9D9}\x{1F9DA}\x{1F9DB}\x{1F9DC}\x{1F9DD}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F645}\x{1F646}\x{1F481}\x{1F64B}\x{1F647}\x{1F926}\x{1F937}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F6B6}\x{1F3C3}\x{1F9D6}\x{1F9D7}\x{1F9D8}\x{1F3CC}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F3CA}\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}\x{1F6B4}\x{1F6B5}\x{1F938}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F939}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{2640}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F46E}\x{1F575}\x{1F482}\x{1F477}\x{1F473}\x{1F471}\x{1F9D9}\x{1F9DA}\x{1F9DB}\x{1F9DC}\x{1F9DD}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F645}\x{1F646}\x{1F481}\x{1F64B}\x{1F647}\x{1F926}\x{1F937}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F6B6}\x{1F3C3}\x{1F9D6}\x{1F9D7}\x{1F9D8}\x{1F3CC}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F3CA}\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}\x{1F6B4}\x{1F6B5}\x{1F938}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F939}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{2640}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F46E}\x{1F575}\x{1F482}\x{1F477}\x{1F473}\x{1F471}\x{1F9D9}\x{1F9DA}\x{1F9DB}\x{1F9DC}\x{1F9DD}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F645}\x{1F646}\x{1F481}\x{1F64B}\x{1F647}\x{1F926}\x{1F937}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F6B6}\x{1F3C3}\x{1F9D6}\x{1F9D7}\x{1F9D8}\x{1F3CC}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F3CA}\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}\x{1F6B4}\x{1F6B5}\x{1F938}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F939}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{2640}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F46E}\x{1F575}\x{1F482}\x{1F477}\x{1F473}\x{1F471}\x{1F9D9}\x{1F9DA}\x{1F9DB}\x{1F9DC}\x{1F9DD}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F645}\x{1F646}\x{1F481}\x{1F64B}\x{1F647}\x{1F926}\x{1F937}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F6B6}\x{1F3C3}\x{1F9D6}\x{1F9D7}\x{1F9D8}\x{1F3CC}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F3CA}\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}\x{1F6B4}\x{1F6B5}\x{1F938}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F939}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{2640}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F46E}\x{1F9B8}\x{1F9B9}\x{1F482}\x{1F477}\x{1F473}\x{1F471}\x{1F9D9}\x{1F9DA}\x{1F9DB}\x{1F9DC}\x{1F9DD}\x{1F9DE}\x{1F9DF}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F645}\x{1F646}\x{1F481}\x{1F64B}\x{1F647}\x{1F926}\x{1F937}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F6B6}\x{1F3C3}\x{1F46F}\x{1F9D6}\x{1F9D7}\x{1F9D8}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F3CA}\x{1F6B4}\x{1F6B5}\x{1F938}\x{1F93C}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F939}](?:\x{200D}\x{2640}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F46E}\x{1F575}\x{1F482}\x{1F477}\x{1F473}\x{1F471}\x{1F9D9}\x{1F9DA}\x{1F9DB}\x{1F9DC}\x{1F9DD}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F645}\x{1F646}\x{1F481}\x{1F64B}\x{1F647}\x{1F926}\x{1F937}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F6B6}\x{1F3C3}\x{1F9D6}\x{1F9D7}\x{1F9D8}\x{1F3CC}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F3CA}\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}\x{1F6B4}\x{1F6B5}\x{1F938}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F939}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{2642}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F46E}\x{1F575}\x{1F482}\x{1F477}\x{1F473}\x{1F471}\x{1F9D9}\x{1F9DA}\x{1F9DB}\x{1F9DC}\x{1F9DD}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F645}\x{1F646}\x{1F481}\x{1F64B}\x{1F647}\x{1F926}\x{1F937}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F6B6}\x{1F3C3}\x{1F9D6}\x{1F9D7}\x{1F9D8}\x{1F3CC}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F3CA}\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}\x{1F6B4}\x{1F6B5}\x{1F938}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F939}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{2642}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F46E}\x{1F575}\x{1F482}\x{1F477}\x{1F473}\x{1F471}\x{1F9D9}\x{1F9DA}\x{1F9DB}\x{1F9DC}\x{1F9DD}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F645}\x{1F646}\x{1F481}\x{1F64B}\x{1F647}\x{1F926}\x{1F937}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F6B6}\x{1F3C3}\x{1F9D6}\x{1F9D7}\x{1F9D8}\x{1F3CC}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F3CA}\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}\x{1F6B4}\x{1F6B5}\x{1F938}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F939}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{2642}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F46E}\x{1F575}\x{1F482}\x{1F477}\x{1F473}\x{1F471}\x{1F9D9}\x{1F9DA}\x{1F9DB}\x{1F9DC}\x{1F9DD}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F645}\x{1F646}\x{1F481}\x{1F64B}\x{1F647}\x{1F926}\x{1F937}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F6B6}\x{1F3C3}\x{1F9D6}\x{1F9D7}\x{1F9D8}\x{1F3CC}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F3CA}\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}\x{1F6B4}\x{1F6B5}\x{1F938}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F939}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{2642}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F46E}\x{1F575}\x{1F482}\x{1F477}\x{1F473}\x{1F471}\x{1F9D9}\x{1F9DA}\x{1F9DB}\x{1F9DC}\x{1F9DD}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F645}\x{1F646}\x{1F481}\x{1F64B}\x{1F647}\x{1F926}\x{1F937}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F6B6}\x{1F3C3}\x{1F9D6}\x{1F9D7}\x{1F9D8}\x{1F3CC}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F3CA}\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}\x{1F6B4}\x{1F6B5}\x{1F938}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F939}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{2642}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F46E}\x{1F9B8}\x{1F9B9}\x{1F482}\x{1F477}\x{1F473}\x{1F471}\x{1F9D9}\x{1F9DA}\x{1F9DB}\x{1F9DC}\x{1F9DD}\x{1F9DE}\x{1F9DF}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F645}\x{1F646}\x{1F481}\x{1F64B}\x{1F647}\x{1F926}\x{1F937}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F6B6}\x{1F3C3}\x{1F46F}\x{1F9D6}\x{1F9D7}\x{1F9D8}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F3CA}\x{1F6B4}\x{1F6B5}\x{1F938}\x{1F93C}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F939}](?:\x{200D}\x{2642}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{1F692})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{1F692})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{1F692})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{1F692})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{1F692})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F692})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{1F680})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{1F680})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{1F680})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{1F680})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{1F680})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F680})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{2708}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{2708}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{2708}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{2708}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{2708}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{2708}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{1F3A8})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{1F3A8})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{1F3A8})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{1F3A8})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{1F3A8})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F3A8})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{1F3A4})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{1F3A4})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{1F3A4})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{1F3A4})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{1F3A4})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F3A4})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{1F4BB})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{1F4BB})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{1F4BB})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{1F4BB})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{1F4BB})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F4BB})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{1F52C})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{1F52C})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{1F52C})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{1F52C})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{1F52C})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F52C})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{1F4BC})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{1F4BC})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{1F4BC})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{1F4BC})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{1F4BC})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F4BC})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{1F3ED})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{1F3ED})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{1F3ED})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{1F3ED})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{1F3ED})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F3ED})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{1F527})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{1F527})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{1F527})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{1F527})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{1F527})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F527})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{1F373})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{1F373})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{1F373})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{1F373})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{1F373})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F373})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{1F33E})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{1F33E})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{1F33E})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{1F33E})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{1F33E})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F33E})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{2696}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{2696}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{2696}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{2696}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{2696}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{2696}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{1F3EB})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{1F3EB})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{1F3EB})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{1F3EB})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{1F3EB})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F3EB})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{1F393})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{1F393})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{1F393})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{1F393})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{1F393})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F393})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{2695}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{2695}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{2695}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{2695}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{2695}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{2695}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F476}\x{1F9D2}\x{1F466}\x{1F467}\x{1F9D1}\x{1F468}\x{1F469}\x{1F9D3}\x{1F474}\x{1F475}\x{1F46E}\x{1F575}\x{1F482}\x{1F477}\x{1F934}\x{1F478}\x{1F473}\x{1F472}\x{1F9D5}\x{1F9D4}\x{1F471}\x{1F935}\x{1F470}\x{1F930}\x{1F931}\x{1F47C}\x{1F385}\x{1F936}\x{1F9D9}\x{1F9DA}\x{1F9DB}\x{1F9DC}\x{1F9DD}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F645}\x{1F646}\x{1F481}\x{1F64B}\x{1F647}\x{1F926}\x{1F937}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F6B6}\x{1F3C3}\x{1F483}\x{1F57A}\x{1F9D6}\x{1F9D7}\x{1F9D8}\x{1F6C0}\x{1F6CC}\x{1F574}\x{1F3C7}\x{1F3C2}\x{1F3CC}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F3CA}\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}\x{1F6B4}\x{1F6B5}\x{1F938}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F939}\x{1F933}\x{1F4AA}\x{1F9B5}\x{1F9B6}\x{1F448}\x{1F449}\x{261D}\x{1F446}\x{1F595}\x{1F447}\x{270C}\x{1F91E}\x{1F596}\x{1F918}\x{1F919}\x{1F590}\x{270B}\x{1F44C}\x{1F44D}\x{1F44E}\x{270A}\x{1F44A}\x{1F91B}\x{1F91C}\x{1F91A}\x{1F44B}\x{1F91F}\x{270D}\x{1F44F}\x{1F450}\x{1F64C}\x{1F932}\x{1F64F}\x{1F485}\x{1F442}\x{1F443}](?:\x{1F3FF})|[\x{1F476}\x{1F9D2}\x{1F466}\x{1F467}\x{1F9D1}\x{1F468}\x{1F469}\x{1F9D3}\x{1F474}\x{1F475}\x{1F46E}\x{1F575}\x{1F482}\x{1F477}\x{1F934}\x{1F478}\x{1F473}\x{1F472}\x{1F9D5}\x{1F9D4}\x{1F471}\x{1F935}\x{1F470}\x{1F930}\x{1F931}\x{1F47C}\x{1F385}\x{1F936}\x{1F9D9}\x{1F9DA}\x{1F9DB}\x{1F9DC}\x{1F9DD}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F645}\x{1F646}\x{1F481}\x{1F64B}\x{1F647}\x{1F926}\x{1F937}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F6B6}\x{1F3C3}\x{1F483}\x{1F57A}\x{1F9D6}\x{1F9D7}\x{1F9D8}\x{1F6C0}\x{1F6CC}\x{1F574}\x{1F3C7}\x{1F3C2}\x{1F3CC}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F3CA}\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}\x{1F6B4}\x{1F6B5}\x{1F938}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F939}\x{1F933}\x{1F4AA}\x{1F9B5}\x{1F9B6}\x{1F448}\x{1F449}\x{261D}\x{1F446}\x{1F595}\x{1F447}\x{270C}\x{1F91E}\x{1F596}\x{1F918}\x{1F919}\x{1F590}\x{270B}\x{1F44C}\x{1F44D}\x{1F44E}\x{270A}\x{1F44A}\x{1F91B}\x{1F91C}\x{1F91A}\x{1F44B}\x{1F91F}\x{270D}\x{1F44F}\x{1F450}\x{1F64C}\x{1F932}\x{1F64F}\x{1F485}\x{1F442}\x{1F443}](?:\x{1F3FE})|[\x{1F476}\x{1F9D2}\x{1F466}\x{1F467}\x{1F9D1}\x{1F468}\x{1F469}\x{1F9D3}\x{1F474}\x{1F475}\x{1F46E}\x{1F575}\x{1F482}\x{1F477}\x{1F934}\x{1F478}\x{1F473}\x{1F472}\x{1F9D5}\x{1F9D4}\x{1F471}\x{1F935}\x{1F470}\x{1F930}\x{1F931}\x{1F47C}\x{1F385}\x{1F936}\x{1F9D9}\x{1F9DA}\x{1F9DB}\x{1F9DC}\x{1F9DD}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F645}\x{1F646}\x{1F481}\x{1F64B}\x{1F647}\x{1F926}\x{1F937}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F6B6}\x{1F3C3}\x{1F483}\x{1F57A}\x{1F9D6}\x{1F9D7}\x{1F9D8}\x{1F6C0}\x{1F6CC}\x{1F574}\x{1F3C7}\x{1F3C2}\x{1F3CC}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F3CA}\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}\x{1F6B4}\x{1F6B5}\x{1F938}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F939}\x{1F933}\x{1F4AA}\x{1F9B5}\x{1F9B6}\x{1F448}\x{1F449}\x{261D}\x{1F446}\x{1F595}\x{1F447}\x{270C}\x{1F91E}\x{1F596}\x{1F918}\x{1F919}\x{1F590}\x{270B}\x{1F44C}\x{1F44D}\x{1F44E}\x{270A}\x{1F44A}\x{1F91B}\x{1F91C}\x{1F91A}\x{1F44B}\x{1F91F}\x{270D}\x{1F44F}\x{1F450}\x{1F64C}\x{1F932}\x{1F64F}\x{1F485}\x{1F442}\x{1F443}](?:\x{1F3FD})|[\x{1F476}\x{1F9D2}\x{1F466}\x{1F467}\x{1F9D1}\x{1F468}\x{1F469}\x{1F9D3}\x{1F474}\x{1F475}\x{1F46E}\x{1F575}\x{1F482}\x{1F477}\x{1F934}\x{1F478}\x{1F473}\x{1F472}\x{1F9D5}\x{1F9D4}\x{1F471}\x{1F935}\x{1F470}\x{1F930}\x{1F931}\x{1F47C}\x{1F385}\x{1F936}\x{1F9D9}\x{1F9DA}\x{1F9DB}\x{1F9DC}\x{1F9DD}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F645}\x{1F646}\x{1F481}\x{1F64B}\x{1F647}\x{1F926}\x{1F937}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F6B6}\x{1F3C3}\x{1F483}\x{1F57A}\x{1F9D6}\x{1F9D7}\x{1F9D8}\x{1F6C0}\x{1F6CC}\x{1F574}\x{1F3C7}\x{1F3C2}\x{1F3CC}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F3CA}\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}\x{1F6B4}\x{1F6B5}\x{1F938}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F939}\x{1F933}\x{1F4AA}\x{1F9B5}\x{1F9B6}\x{1F448}\x{1F449}\x{261D}\x{1F446}\x{1F595}\x{1F447}\x{270C}\x{1F91E}\x{1F596}\x{1F918}\x{1F919}\x{1F590}\x{270B}\x{1F44C}\x{1F44D}\x{1F44E}\x{270A}\x{1F44A}\x{1F91B}\x{1F91C}\x{1F91A}\x{1F44B}\x{1F91F}\x{270D}\x{1F44F}\x{1F450}\x{1F64C}\x{1F932}\x{1F64F}\x{1F485}\x{1F442}\x{1F443}](?:\x{1F3FC})|[\x{1F476}\x{1F9D2}\x{1F466}\x{1F467}\x{1F9D1}\x{1F468}\x{1F469}\x{1F9D3}\x{1F474}\x{1F475}\x{1F46E}\x{1F575}\x{1F482}\x{1F477}\x{1F934}\x{1F478}\x{1F473}\x{1F472}\x{1F9D5}\x{1F9D4}\x{1F471}\x{1F935}\x{1F470}\x{1F930}\x{1F931}\x{1F47C}\x{1F385}\x{1F936}\x{1F9D9}\x{1F9DA}\x{1F9DB}\x{1F9DC}\x{1F9DD}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F645}\x{1F646}\x{1F481}\x{1F64B}\x{1F647}\x{1F926}\x{1F937}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F6B6}\x{1F3C3}\x{1F483}\x{1F57A}\x{1F9D6}\x{1F9D7}\x{1F9D8}\x{1F6C0}\x{1F6CC}\x{1F574}\x{1F3C7}\x{1F3C2}\x{1F3CC}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F3CA}\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}\x{1F6B4}\x{1F6B5}\x{1F938}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F939}\x{1F933}\x{1F4AA}\x{1F9B5}\x{1F9B6}\x{1F448}\x{1F449}\x{261D}\x{1F446}\x{1F595}\x{1F447}\x{270C}\x{1F91E}\x{1F596}\x{1F918}\x{1F919}\x{1F590}\x{270B}\x{1F44C}\x{1F44D}\x{1F44E}\x{270A}\x{1F44A}\x{1F91B}\x{1F91C}\x{1F91A}\x{1F44B}\x{1F91F}\x{270D}\x{1F44F}\x{1F450}\x{1F64C}\x{1F932}\x{1F64F}\x{1F485}\x{1F442}\x{1F443}](?:\x{1F3FB})|[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1E9}\x{1F1F0}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F3}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1F9}\x{1F1FA}](?:\x{1F1FF})|[\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1F0}\x{1F1F1}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F5}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1FA}](?:\x{1F1FE})|[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F8}](?:\x{1F1FD})|[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1F0}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F5}\x{1F1F7}\x{1F1F9}\x{1F1FF}](?:\x{1F1FC})|[\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1F1}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1F9}](?:\x{1F1FB})|[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1EA}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1ED}\x{1F1F1}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F3}\x{1F1F7}\x{1F1FB}](?:\x{1F1FA})|[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1EA}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1ED}\x{1F1EE}\x{1F1F1}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F5}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1F9}\x{1F1FE}](?:\x{1F1F9})|[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1EA}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1EE}\x{1F1F1}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F5}\x{1F1F7}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1FA}\x{1F1FC}](?:\x{1F1F8})|[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1EA}\x{1F1EB}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1ED}\x{1F1EE}\x{1F1F0}\x{1F1F1}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F3}\x{1F1F5}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1F9}](?:\x{1F1F7})|[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1EE}\x{1F1F2}](?:\x{1F1F6})|[\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1EF}\x{1F1F0}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F3}](?:\x{1F1F5})|[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1E9}\x{1F1EB}\x{1F1EE}\x{1F1EF}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F3}\x{1F1F7}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1F9}](?:\x{1F1F4})|[\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1ED}\x{1F1EE}\x{1F1F0}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F5}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1F9}\x{1F1FA}\x{1F1FB}](?:\x{1F1F3})|[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1E9}\x{1F1EB}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1ED}\x{1F1EE}\x{1F1EF}\x{1F1F0}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F4}\x{1F1F5}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1F9}\x{1F1FA}\x{1F1FF}](?:\x{1F1F2})|[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1EE}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F3}\x{1F1F5}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1F9}](?:\x{1F1F1})|[\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1E9}\x{1F1EB}\x{1F1ED}\x{1F1F1}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F5}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1F9}\x{1F1FD}](?:\x{1F1F0})|[\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E9}\x{1F1EB}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1F9}](?:\x{1F1EF})|[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1EB}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1F0}\x{1F1F1}\x{1F1F3}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1FB}](?:\x{1F1EE})|[\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1EA}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1F0}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F5}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1F9}](?:\x{1F1ED})|[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1E9}\x{1F1EA}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1F0}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F3}\x{1F1F5}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1F9}\x{1F1FA}\x{1F1FB}](?:\x{1F1EC})|[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F3}\x{1F1F5}\x{1F1F9}\x{1F1FC}](?:\x{1F1EB})|[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E9}\x{1F1EA}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1EE}\x{1F1EF}\x{1F1F0}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F3}\x{1F1F5}\x{1F1F7}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1FB}\x{1F1FE}](?:\x{1F1EA})|[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1EE}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1F9}](?:\x{1F1E9})|[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1EA}\x{1F1EE}\x{1F1F1}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F3}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1F9}\x{1F1FB}](?:\x{1F1E8})|[\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1F1}\x{1F1F8}](?:\x{1F1E7})|[\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1EA}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1F1}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F3}\x{1F1F5}\x{1F1F6}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1F9}\x{1F1FA}\x{1F1FB}\x{1F1FF}](?:\x{1F1E6})|[\x{00A9}\x{00AE}\x{203C}\x{2049}\x{2122}\x{2139}\x{2194}-\x{2199}\x{21A9}-\x{21AA}\x{231A}-\x{231B}\x{2328}\x{23CF}\x{23E9}-\x{23F3}\x{23F8}-\x{23FA}\x{24C2}\x{25AA}-\x{25AB}\x{25B6}\x{25C0}\x{25FB}-\x{25FE}\x{2600}-\x{2604}\x{260E}\x{2611}\x{2614}-\x{2615}\x{2618}\x{261D}\x{2620}\x{2622}-\x{2623}\x{2626}\x{262A}\x{262E}-\x{262F}\x{2638}-\x{263A}\x{2640}\x{2642}\x{2648}-\x{2653}\x{2660}\x{2663}\x{2665}-\x{2666}\x{2668}\x{267B}\x{267E}-\x{267F}\x{2692}-\x{2697}\x{2699}\x{269B}-\x{269C}\x{26A0}-\x{26A1}\x{26AA}-\x{26AB}\x{26B0}-\x{26B1}\x{26BD}-\x{26BE}\x{26C4}-\x{26C5}\x{26C8}\x{26CE}-\x{26CF}\x{26D1}\x{26D3}-\x{26D4}\x{26E9}-\x{26EA}\x{26F0}-\x{26F5}\x{26F7}-\x{26FA}\x{26FD}\x{2702}\x{2705}\x{2708}-\x{270D}\x{270F}\x{2712}\x{2714}\x{2716}\x{271D}\x{2721}\x{2728}\x{2733}-\x{2734}\x{2744}\x{2747}\x{274C}\x{274E}\x{2753}-\x{2755}\x{2757}\x{2763}-\x{2764}\x{2795}-\x{2797}\x{27A1}\x{27B0}\x{27BF}\x{2934}-\x{2935}\x{2B05}-\x{2B07}\x{2B1B}-\x{2B1C}\x{2B50}\x{2B55}\x{3030}\x{303D}\x{3297}\x{3299}\x{1F004}\x{1F0CF}\x{1F170}-\x{1F171}\x{1F17E}-\x{1F17F}\x{1F18E}\x{1F191}-\x{1F19A}\x{1F201}-\x{1F202}\x{1F21A}\x{1F22F}\x{1F232}-\x{1F23A}\x{1F250}-\x{1F251}\x{1F300}-\x{1F321}\x{1F324}-\x{1F393}\x{1F396}-\x{1F397}\x{1F399}-\x{1F39B}\x{1F39E}-\x{1F3F0}\x{1F3F3}-\x{1F3F5}\x{1F3F7}-\x{1F3FA}\x{1F400}-\x{1F4FD}\x{1F4FF}-\x{1F53D}\x{1F549}-\x{1F54E}\x{1F550}-\x{1F567}\x{1F56F}-\x{1F570}\x{1F573}-\x{1F57A}\x{1F587}\x{1F58A}-\x{1F58D}\x{1F590}\x{1F595}-\x{1F596}\x{1F5A4}-\x{1F5A5}\x{1F5A8}\x{1F5B1}-\x{1F5B2}\x{1F5BC}\x{1F5C2}-\x{1F5C4}\x{1F5D1}-\x{1F5D3}\x{1F5DC}-\x{1F5DE}\x{1F5E1}\x{1F5E3}\x{1F5E8}\x{1F5EF}\x{1F5F3}\x{1F5FA}-\x{1F64F}\x{1F680}-\x{1F6C5}\x{1F6CB}-\x{1F6D2}\x{1F6E0}-\x{1F6E5}\x{1F6E9}\x{1F6EB}-\x{1F6EC}\x{1F6F0}\x{1F6F3}-\x{1F6F9}\x{1F910}-\x{1F93A}\x{1F93C}-\x{1F93E}\x{1F940}-\x{1F945}\x{1F947}-\x{1F970}\x{1F973}-\x{1F976}\x{1F97A}\x{1F97C}-\x{1F9A2}\x{1F9B0}-\x{1F9B9}\x{1F9C0}-\x{1F9C2}\x{1F9D0}-\x{1F9FF}]/u', '', $text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Дмитрий Шевчук* дал хороший ответ.
Но если вы имеете дело с кириллицей, то нужно добавить буквы Ёё (чтобы не получился Киселв вместо Киселёв) и модификатор 'u', иначе PHP заменит всё непонятное на �
Очень хороший учебник здесь: [Регулярки - Трепачёв](http://old.code.mu/books/php/regular/)
Тогда полный вариант будет выглядеть так:

```
$fullname = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-ZА-Яа-яЁё0-9\s]/u","",$profileinfo['fullname']);
```